# Three.js - dynamically change castShadow property of all meshes

Tags: three.js

I am developing a simple tool for beginner pencil illustrators. It aims to show lights and shadows of simple objects. What I have already got is availaible here http://ayeo.pl/castle
The problem is to change property castShadow and reciveShadow of all meshes (inside scene). I've tried to iterate all objects but it doesn't seem to make any effect.

PS I'm new to three.js

EDIT: I mean to change castShadow when spacebar has been pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some properties can't be easily changed at runtime. See the three.js Wiki article [How to Update Things with WebGLRenderer](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates).

In your case, the easiest thing to do is to enable shadows at the start, and then set `light.shadowDarkness = 0` when you want to turn shadows off.

Tip: You might want to consider using `OrbitControls` to control the camera, and dat.GUI for parameter control, rather than writing the code yourself.

three.js r.63

Comment: Thank you, that's works perfectly. I know about Orbit but I'hv decided to try manage rotations myself.